# Run azure store procedure from azure function

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

Is it possible to run a Cosmos DB stored procedure (sp created in azure portal) from azure Functions (for example time trigger).

Whay I need is by the time trigger to query documents in collection (input binding), modify some fields in it and update (like `DocumentClient.UpsertDocumentAsync`) and store back updated document to the collection.

Comment: Yes you can run stored procedures from an Azure function. The rest of the question I can't understand.

Comment: There's no binding for SQL database, but you can use any library you want like Dapper or plain ADO.NET.

Comment: I don't need SQL db, I need to call Azure stored procedure from Azure Functions.

Comment: @Crowcoder, how, please? :)

Comment: There is virtually no difference between calling stored procedures in Azure SQL and any other instance of SQL Server. If you do some research and try your own code we can help with problems you might encounter.

Comment: @ValeriyLyuchyn how what? There's no `Azure stored procedure`. There are stored procedures in Azure SQL or other databases. Perhaps you mean something different when you say `Azure stored procedure`?

Comment: @ValeriyLyuchyn are you asking how to call *CosmosDB* stored procedures? Have you tried [ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.executestoredprocedureasync?view=azure-dotnet) ? Post your code. You are forcing people to *guess* what you want or even what database you are talking about

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, exactly, I need to call CosmosDB stored procedure

Comment: @ValeriyLyuchyn and? Did you use `ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync`? Update the question, post your code and explain the problem. You can't expect an answer when you don't provide any information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1 : please create your stored procedure in your cosmos db.

***sample stored procedure js code:***

```
function sample() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT * FROM root r where r.id = "1"',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var a = new Date();
            var doc = feed[0];
            doc.time = a;
            collection.replaceDocument(doc._self,doc,function(err) {
                                                        if (err) throw err;
                                                     });
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody(JSON.stringify("update success"));
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Step 2: Create c# azure function TimeTrigger.

***sample function code:***

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;


public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    private static DocumentClient client;

    static string endpoint = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
    static string key = "***";
    client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), key);
    StoredProcedureResponse<bool> sprocResponse = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<bool>(
                                                                "/dbs/db/colls/coll/sprocs/updatetest/");
    if (sprocResponse.Response) log.Info(sprocResponse.Response);
    log.Info($"Cosmos DB is updated at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

Step 3: Add document db assembly referencing in azure-functions.

You could click Azure function>View file>add a new file named `'project.json'`(if it does not exist).Write the following code in this file then click run to install package:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB": "1.20.1"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

More details , you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried the above code and I am getting below error. Pleas have a look. @Jay Gong

Comment: @Antony Did you open a case for your issue?

Comment: No. Do we need to register DB, Collection and StoredProcedure somewhere before executing this code or directly passing their names in String parameter will work?

Comment: @Antony Yes, of course you need to create those services and items before you use them in Azure Function.

Comment: @Antony I notice that you created a azure-function related case.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about case. I didn't get that! @Jay

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. Now I am able to execute a SP from Azure time triggering function.@Jay